# Is compensation available for requested data improperly withheld and deleted against data subject’s wishes?

Tags: england-and-wales, data-protection, subject-access-request

Bob requests data from ACME. They ask him for identification according to very unreasonable and onerous requirements. He objects to these on grounds of infeasibility and inaccessibility. They bicker back and forth and in the course of this his data is routinely deleted.

What are the consequences of this?

Specifically, can inferences as to the possible contents of the requested data be drawn in the context of other matters? And, is there financial compensation available to Bob?

Comment: What is the data presumed to contain?  How/why does Bob believe he has any right to ACME's data?  In what way is their request for ID unreasonable?  What sort of financial loss has Bob incurred?  This needs way more detail...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incomplete/unserviceable SAR submissions and deletion timeframes](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/85336/incomplete-unserviceable-sar-submissions-and-deletion-timeframes)

Comment: @MichaelHall see https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/95474/how-is-compensation-and-other-consequences-for-abrogating-data-subject-rights-un for an example of an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

### What [damage](https://ico.org.uk/for-the-public/data-protection-and-journalism/taking-your-case-to-court-and-claiming-compensation) has Bob suffered?

Let’s assume that the company has breached privacy law. That is a necessary but not sufficient criteria for Bob to receive compensation. Bob must also have suffered damage as a result of the breach.

Comment: See also https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/95474/how-is-compensation-and-other-consequences-for-abrogating-data-subject-rights-un