# Does RIPA 3000 require service providers to retain the contents rather than merely metadata of SMS communications?

Tags: england-and-wales

The question is not deeper than what is articulated in its title

Comment: Perhaps, but a) not confidently, b) with no reference given, and c) it isn’t *asked* there.

Comment: D) if anything only as a sidenote

Comment: The question is not deeper than what is articulated in your other question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SARing received text messages from a lost phone](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/93543/saring-received-text-messages-from-a-lost-phone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the [Regulation of Investigatory Powers Act 2000](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/23/contents) (aka RIPA), it doesn't provide for mandatory [retention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_retention) of communications data. Broadly speaking, RIPA is about *interception* as opposed to mass surveillance or retention just in case.

The [Data Retention (EC Directive) Regulations 2009](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2009/859/contents/made) obliged "public communications providers" to retain what is commonly known as 'metadata', i.e. information *about* the communication - the originating phone number, the receiving phone number, the date, time and duration (if relevant), the type of call or message - not the content of the communication. See [Schedule 1](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2009/859/schedule/made).

In April 2014, in the case known as *[Digital Rights Ireland](https://curia.europa.eu/juris/documents.jsf?num=C-293/12)* the Court of Justice of the European Union declared the EC Directive invalid.

In response, the UK made the [Data Retention and Investigatory Powers Act 2014](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2014/27/contents) (DRIPA) - sunsetted on 31 December 2016. This provided for the Secretary of State to issue a data retention notice to a communications services provider (CSP), requiring it to retain the data types set out in the Schedule to the 2009 Regulations. [DRIPA's Explanatory Notes](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2014/27/notes/division/3/1) support my claims above with a summary of the history.

This was replaced by the [Investigatory Powers Act 2016](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25/contents/enacted) (IPA), Part 4 of which deals with the [retention of communications data](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25/part/4/enacted). Here too the retention is of the metadata not the content (see s11(87) and the [Explanatory Notes](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25/notes/division/6/index.htm)).